# jest/enzyme test: this.props.showOverlay is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a small test that simulates a click (hoping to do more with the test, but this is where I'm stuck so far):

```
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import HamburgerIcon from './HamburgerIcon';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test('hamburger icon changes class and state on click', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<HamburgerIcon />);
  const hamburgerIcon = wrapper.find('div#mobile-nav');

  hamburgerIcon.simulate('click');
});
```

When running this test, I get the error:

> TypeError: this.props.showOverlay is not a function

After doing some reading, I've realized that this isn't working because the simulated click calls a function that is two levels up from the component that is being tested (`HamburgerIcon`).

When I first tried to run this, I was using Enzyme's `shallow`, and I since changed it to `mount` thinking that this would give the test access to the `showOverlay` function, but I was wrong.

Then I read that this might be a good use case for a [mock function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions), and I tried to start implementing this:

```
...

const showOverlay = jest.fn();
// how to set this.props.ShowOverlay to the const above??

test('has div with class .closed', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<HamburgerIcon />);
  const hamburgerIcon = wrapper.find('div#mobile-nav');

  hamburgerIcon.simulate('click');
});
```

This is where I am sort of lost -- I'm not sure if mock functions are the right direction here, and I'm also not sure how the syntax of setting up the mock function will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue with `shallow` if you're just unit testing a single component. If this component is nested and you're testing against child nodes, then you'll `mount` the parent.

That said, you're on the right track for using a mock function. Simply pass it into the component like so:

`<HamburgerIcon showOverlay={showOverlay} />`

For example:

```
const showOverlay = jest.fn();

test('shows an overlay', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<HamburgerIcon showOverlay={showOverlay} />);
  const hamburgerIcon = wrapper.find('div#mobile-nav');

  hamburgerIcon.simulate('click');
  expect(showOverlay).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

---

If you have multiple props, then I like to do something more declarative:

```
// define props here if you want an easy way check if they've been 
// called (since we're defining at the top-level, all tests have access
// to this function)
const showOverlay = jest.fn();

// then include them in an "initialProps" object (you can also just define
// them within this object as well, but you'll have to use 
// "initialProps.nameOfFunction" to check if they're called -- kind of 
// repetitive if you have a lot of props that you're checking against)
const initialProps = {
  showOverlay,
  someOtherFunction: jest.fn()
}

// use the spread syntax to pass all the props in the "initialProps" object
// to the component
test('shows an overlay', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<HamburgerIcon { ...initialProps } />);
  const hamburgerIcon = wrapper.find('div#mobile-nav');

  hamburgerIcon.simulate('click');

  expect(showOverlay).toHaveBeenCalled(); // here we can just use the mock function name
  expect(initialProps.someOtherFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0); // here we'll have to use "initialProps.property" because it has been scoped to the object
});
```